# How do I verify that my home mains power is consistent?

Tags: electrical

I live in a rental apartment (in the Netherlands, if that's relevant to power). I have observed some things that suggest to me that my mains power supply may fluctuate significantly in voltage (or current?), including that some simple electric fans sometimes slow down a lot before slowly speeding back up again. I'm concerned that this may affect things like sensitive digital appliances.

What non-invasive method can I use to check the consistency of the power supply? I'm willing to buy cheap tools that help with this.

Comment: Any simple mulitmeter will check voltage.  Just need to test outlets.  There are also monitoring meters that you plug into an outlet and plug lights/fans/whatever into the meter, they have the advantage of not needing you to get the mulitmeter out all the time. Watt meter is one name they go by.  It does sound like you are not getting consistent power, might be brown outs cause by the power company, or neighbours/factories nearby using too much power at a time(startup of large motors)

Comment: "recording voltmeter"

Comment: Does your apartment get 1 phase of power, or all 3?  Does the power come to the building via an overhead cable? Can you see the ends of it?

Answer (score 4):

Many power companies will come out and install a 72 hour recorder that monitors voltage at the meter. See if your' does this. It's a common solution when customers complain about low voltage. It's usually done free of charge.

Answer (score 3):

When we first moved into our house, we suffered from frequent brown outs - enough of a dip in power to reset the digital clocks and cause computers to reboot. I purchased a UPS for my computer.

My UPS had a data connection that plugged into the computer and via the application, I was able to see current input voltage, as well as getting a record of every dip in power and every time that the UPS switched to battery power to protect the computer.

As time went on, I added more UPSs for more of my electronic devices. Now, basically everything that's electronic (not electric - the dryer, oven and fridge are *not* included) is on a UPS. The power company seems to have long ago fixed the frequent brownout issues, but all my devices do survive the occasional power dip without me having to reset their clocks, and I can go around the house and shut down all the electronics in an orderly fashion should the power go out and stay out for more than a few minutes. As an even greater bonus, all the computers can communicate with their UPS, so if the power goes out and I'm not home, the computers are still shut down in an orderly fashion, though the TV and networking equipment will still, effectively, "have the plug pulled" when the UPS battery dies.

While a UPS is *definitely* overkill for simply measuring voltage at the outlet, it will protect your computer *and* give you the data you're after. It will be handy to protect the sensitive electronics while you're waiting for the power company to fix the issue (assuming there is one), and will provide peace of mind even once that has been taken care of.

Answer (score 1):

The concern is *voltage*. Electric power - what your devices actually use - is essentially (ignoring power factor) voltage x current. Utility systems for over a hundred years have been designed for constant voltage (e.g., 230V or 240V) with current varying by usage. Turn on a 2,000 W heater and you will use an additional 8.33A if you are on a 240V system. There will be *some* variation, and devices are normally designed to handle at least 5% without any significant effect.

There are a number of different things that can cause significant variations in voltage. The first step is to monitor your voltage to see what is going on. The ideal thing to do is to monitor at your main breaker panel. However, that is not necessarily possible, depending on design and access. This is especially the case for a rental. The next best thing is to monitor at individual receptacles. The catch is you need to find a device designed for your particular location as plug/receptacle types vary around the world. You plug a device (light, fan, etc.) into the monitor and see what happens. Some monitors only record minimum and maximum, but if you can find one that records (or transmits to your phone or computer) frequent readings that is even better.

Once you have more information, try to see if it correlates to any activity in your home or any particular time. Then go to your landlord and report the information. This may be a utility problem or it may be a building problem, but since you are in a rental the starting point is your landlord. The utility (except for responding to outages) normally won't do anything without permission of the landlord.

Answer (score 1):

There are many cheap devices that will record voltage.    I won't recommend specific ones because I don't know what's easily available in the Netherlands but there are two common kinds:

1. Energy monitors. You attach these to your electric panel or consumer unit and they monitor energy usage, but they also monitor and record voltage.  You can also buy these for single electrical outlets.  They usually allow you remote control on/off of the outlet and they record energy use and voltage.  You'll have to shop for one where the recording frequency is granular enough to detect the problems you are having.
2. Recording oscilloscopes.  There are some very cheap USB and Bluetooth ones now, they don't include any screen or UI, they need a computer or phone app.  But they are CHEAP, you can set the recording frequency, they run independently when recording.   If you don't care about high frequency measurements (and you don't) you can get one under $50 US in the US .. again I'm not sure about over there.

The energy monitors are designed for recording every minute or second, which may not be enough for you. The "oscilloscopes" are designed for thousands or millions or samples per second, so a VERY cheap one will be more than adequate.